# HBase Map-only Row Delete

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

First time writing a HBase mapreduce and I'm having trouble deleting rows in HBase (trying to run it as a map-only job). The job succeeds and is able to scan the HBase table and I'm able to get the correct rowkeys in the mapper read from HBase (verified through sysout). However, it seems like the call to `Delete del = new Delete(row.get())` isn't actually doing anything.

Below is the code I'm trying to run:

HBaseDelete.java

```
public class HBaseDelete { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Job job = new Job(config, "log_table");
    job.setJarByClass(HBaseDeleteMapper.class);     

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500);        
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("log_table", scan, HBaseDeleteMapper.class, null, null, job);

    job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    if (!b) {
        throw new IOException("error with job!");
    }

  }
}
```

HBaseDeleteMapper.java

```
public class HBaseDeleteMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Delete>{
  @Override
  public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Delete delete = new Delete(row.get());
    context.write(row, delete);
  }
}
```

Is there something missing to 'commit' the deletion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're writing to the context, not to the table, your mapper should look somewhat similar to this one:

```
public class HBaseDeleteMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, NullWritable>{

    private HTable myTable;

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /* HTable instance for deletes */
        myTable = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create(), "myTable".getBytes());
    }

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        myTable.delete(new Delete(row.get())); /* Delete the row from the table */
        //context.write(row, NullWritable.get()); /* Just an output with deleted rows if you need it for something (avoid it if you not) */
    }

    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
        myTable.close(); /* Close table */
    }

}
```

Please notice that delete operations don't use the write buffer, this code will issue 1 RPC operation per delete, which is not good for this type of jobs. To address that you can build your own `List<Delete>` to batch them:

```
public class HBaseDeleteMapper extends TableMapper<NullWritable, NullWritable>{

    private HTable myTable;
    private List<Delete> deleteList = new ArrayList<Delete>();
    final private int buffer = 10000; /* Buffer size, tune it as desired */

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /* HTable instance for deletes */
        myTable = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create(), "myTable".getBytes());
    }

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        deleteList.add(new Delete(row.get())); /* Add delete to the batch */
        if (deleteList.size()==buffer) {
            myTable.delete(deleteList); /* Submit batch */
            deleteList.clear(); /* Clear batch */
        }
    }

    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (deleteList.size()>0) {
            myTable.delete(deleteList); /* Submit remaining batch */
        }
        myTable.close(); /* Close table */
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben, that works for me :) But as you mentioned it is an expensive operation. Since 'map' is given the row per call (rowkey based on the scan filtering & etc.), would you then need to build the list first in the map and then call the delete operation in the reducer?

Comment: Avoid writing anything to the context if you don't have to: the shuffle/sort of the map/reduce job will take forever.  I would modify Ruben's code to add the delete to a List, like he suggests, and then have a batch size that kicks off the delete once your list fills up.  You will also have to kick off the delete in the cleanup method.  It may be more complicated than that if you can't send a full List to HBase in one delete call.

Comment: You don't need further processing, just avoid the reduce phase at all as @David suggest. I've updated my response with an example ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips on avoiding context/reduce if un-needed @David and thanks for the update Ruben, I've got it working properly as per the advice from yesterday :)

Comment: Useful answer. I have a suggestion followed by a question. I noticed that the OP has not used any filters anywhere, so I feel a table truncate_preserve would be a much simpler answer only in the context of not having any filters. Question, if I have a table with about 1 billion rows and I use a scan filter fetching only about a few millions,  would it lead to scanner timeout exception as millions of records are ignored due to the filter? I had an instance like this before to filter records into my MR which always failed due to scanner timeout. I can post this as a question is required.

Answer (score 1):

### COMPLETE CODE

Below code will scan you hbase table for rowkeys containing a substring in common and deletes them when size of list is > 1000(this is to make sure that your list does not blow out of space/heap space) .Code also writes these row keys to your hdfs .

Driver

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.oclc.wcsync.hadoop.mapper.HbaseBulkDeleteMapper;
import org.oclc.wcsync.hadoop.util.JobName;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;

/** doc. */
public class HbaseBulkDelete extends Configured implements Tool{

    /** doc. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HbaseBulkDelete.class);


    /**
     * doc.
     * @param args ...
     * @throws Exception ...
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(HBaseConfiguration.create(), new HbaseBulkDelete(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {


        JobName jobName = JobName.HBASE_DELETE;
        LOG.info ("Got into class driver");
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create ();
        String env = "prod";
        Properties hadoopProps = new Properties();
        hadoopProps.load(HbaseBulkDelete.class.getResourceAsStream("/hadoop.config." + env + ".properties"));
        conf.set("jobName", jobName.name());
        conf.set ("hbase.master.catalog.timeout","600000");
        conf.set ("hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period","600000");
        conf.set ("hbase.rpc.timeout","6000000");
        conf.set ("mapred.task.timeout","6000000");
        conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb","4096");
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJobName(jobName.format("HbaseBulkDelete"));
        job.setJarByClass(HbaseBulkDelete.class);
        Scan s = new Scan ();
        s.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("data"));
        s.setStartRow (Bytes.toBytes ("Your_Substring"));

        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob ("Ingest", s, HbaseBulkDeleteMapper.class, TextOutputFormat.class,
                TextOutputFormat.class, job);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/neethu/HbaseBulkDelete"));


        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

### MAPPER

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HbaseBulkDeleteMapper extends TableMapper<Text, Text> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HbaseBulkDeleteMapper.class);
    Configuration conf;
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        conf = context.getConfiguration();

    }
    List<Delete> listOfBatchDelete = new ArrayList<Delete> ();
    @Override
    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HTable table= new HTable(conf,"Ingest");
        if (listOfBatchDelete != null && !listOfBatchDelete.isEmpty () && listOfBatchDelete.size () > 1000) {
            LOG.info ("Deleted records!");

            listOfBatchDelete.clear ();
        }
        String KEY=Bytes.toString(values.getRow ());
        try {
            if (KEY.contains ("Your_substring") ){
                LOG.info ("RowKey:"+KEY );
                Delete d=new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(KEY));
                listOfBatchDelete.add(d);
                context.write (new Text ("RowKey"), new Text (KEY));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error ("error  ---" + e);
        }
       // table.delete(listOfBatchDelete);
    }
}
```