# I want to do a bulk delete on a hbase table

Tags: hbase

I found a answer on Stack overflow and tried it -     [HBase Map-only Row Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291236/hbase-map-only-row-delete) . But it throws a error as

> Output directory not set in JobConf.

How to fix this? My code is same as in the link. Little difference in the logic. I'm giving a range of keys. I hope it is not the problem.

```
    int startRange = 1;
    int endRange = 10 ;
    String key;
    for(int i=startRange;i<=endRange;i++){
        key = ""+i;
        Delete d=new Delete(Bytes.toBytes(key));
        deleteList.add(d);
    }
    myTable.delete(deleteList);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: @Rubén Moraleda can you help me?

Comment: @eangeles  can you help me?